# PyDap and Xarray remote access to LP DAAC

Tags: python-xarray, opendap

I would like to use xarray/pydap for remote access of data on the [LP DAAC](https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/) OpeNDAP server.

I have an earth data account (username and password - [login page](https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/)), and I have added the LP DAAC OpeNDAP application to my list of approved applications.

Below is my effort to access the data. Has anyone else been able to access data via opendap from LP DAAC? Is my url correct? Does this look like a server side (opendap) issue?

Example Code:

```
from pydap.client import open_url
from pydap.cas.urs import setup_session
import xarray as xr

dataset_url = 'https://opendap.cr.usgs.gov/opendap/hyrax/MOD13Q1.006/h00v08.ncml.nc4'

### Replace with your username and password
session = setup_session('XXXX', 'XXXXXX', check_url=dataset_url)
store = xr.backends.PydapDataStore.open(dataset_url, session=session)
ds = xr.open_dataset(store)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-0ddf552f3174> in <module>
----> 1 store = xr.backends.PydapDataStore.open(dataset_url, session=session)
      2 ds = xr.open_dataset(store)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/pydap_.py in open(cls, url, session)
     71     def open(cls, url, session=None):
     72         import pydap.client
---> 73         ds = pydap.client.open_url(url, session=session)
     74         return cls(ds)
     75 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydap/client.py in open_url(url, application, session, output_grid, timeout)
     65     """
     66     dataset = DAPHandler(url, application, session, output_grid,
---> 67                          timeout).dataset
     68 
     69     # attach server-side functions

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydap/handlers/dap.py in __init__(self, url, application, session, output_grid, timeout)
     52         ddsurl = urlunsplit((scheme, netloc, path + '.dds', query, fragment))
     53         r = GET(ddsurl, application, session, timeout=timeout)
---> 54         raise_for_status(r)
     55         if not r.charset:
     56             r.charset = 'ascii'

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydap/net.py in raise_for_status(response)
     37             detail=response.status+'\n'+response.text,
     38             headers=response.headers,
---> 39             comment=response.body
     40         )
     41 

HTTPError: 404 Not Found





<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/opendap/docs/css/contents.css' type='text/css'/>
    <title>Hyrax: Resource Not Found</title>
</head>

<body>
<p align="left">&nbsp;</p>

<h1 align="center">Hyrax - Resource Not Found (404) </h1>
<hr align="left" size="1" noshade="noshade"/>
<table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="/opendap/docs/images/largeEarth.jpg">
            <img src="/opendap/docs/images/smallEarth.jpg"
                 alt="I looked everywhere!"
                 title="I looked everywhere!"
                 border="0"/>
            </a>
        </td>

        <td>
            <p align="left">The URL requested does not describe a resource that can be found on this server.</p>

            <p align="left">If you would like to start at the top level of this server, go <a
                    href="/opendap/"><strong>HERE</strong></a>.</p>


            <p align="left">The specific error message associated with your request was:</p>
            <blockquote> <p><strong>Failed to locate resource: /MOD13Q1.006/h00v08.ncml.nc4.dds </strong></p> </blockquote>

            <p align="left">If you think that the server is broken (that the URL you submitted should have worked),
                then please contact the OPeNDAP user support coordinator at: <a href="mailto:lpdaac@usgs.gov">lpdaac@usgs.gov</a>
            </p>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr align="left" size="1" noshade="noshade"/>
<h1 align="center">Hyrax - Resource Not Found (404) </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Version information:

```
xr.show_versions()
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 27 2019, 23:01:00) 
[GCC 7.3.0]
python-bits: 64
OS: Linux
OS-release: 4.4.0-150-generic
machine: x86_64
processor: x86_64
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: en_US.UTF-8
LANG: en_US.UTF-8
LOCALE: en_US.UTF-8
libhdf5: 1.10.4
libnetcdf: 4.6.2

xarray: 0.12.1
pandas: 0.24.2
numpy: 1.15.4
scipy: 1.2.1
netCDF4: 1.5.1.2
pydap: installed
h5netcdf: None
h5py: 2.9.0
Nio: None
zarr: 2.3.2
cftime: 1.0.3.4
nc_time_axis: None
PseudonetCDF: None
rasterio: 1.0.24
cfgrib: None
iris: None
bottleneck: 1.2.1
dask: 1.2.2
distributed: 1.28.0
matplotlib: 3.0.3
cartopy: 0.17.0
seaborn: 0.9.0
setuptools: 41.0.1
pip: 19.1.1
conda: 4.6.14
pytest: None
IPython: 7.5.0
sphinx: None
```